# Deleted branch unexpectedly git in visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, git-branch

I am working in visual studio 2013 with git and today unexpectedly i deleted a branch . Now when i go to create branch it doesn't show in drop-down to select and create that again .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Create a list of all unreachable commits.

```
git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found
```

**Step 2:**

Print a list of commit messages for all commits in the lost and found.

```
ls -1 .git/lost-found/commit/ | xargs -n 1 git log -n 1 --pretty=oneline
```

**Step 3:**

Search for your missing commit. Create a new branch with the missing commit as the branch head.

```
git checkout -b branch-name SHA
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Do `git reflog` and find the SHA-1 hash of the last commit (i.e. the head) of the branch you just deleted.
2. Do `git checkout -b <SHA-1>` where `SHA-1` corresponds to the commit you found in Step 1.

Comment: is there any way to do this thing from visual studio OR i have to do this with git command prompt ?

Comment: I could not find any way to run `git reflog` from Visual Studio, and this step is necessary to find your lost branch.  I welcome a comment, edit, or new answer which can restore a branch using only the Git plugin.

Comment: i just installed git bash right now and try to run `git reflog` , but error is `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'`

Comment: This sounds like your branch has become corrupted.  Try opening the commit log for the branch in question.  You may have to abandon the HEAD of the deleted branch.